# Solving a discrete square inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I am looking for the solution for $n$ to a numeric inequality for a given natural number $x$,

$ 1+4n(n-1) \leq x \leq 4n(n+1) $ where $ n,x \in \mathbb{N} $

I know that there is exactly one number $n$ for each $x$. Can $n$ be calculated for a known $x$?

**Background:**

For a game I want to partition my (endless) world into a radial layout of 'plots', consisting of rings around a central plot 0 like this:

```
----------------
| 9|10|11|12|13|
----------------
|24| 1| 2| 3|14|
----------------
|23| 8| 0| 4|15|
----------------
|22| 7| 6| 5|16|
----------------
|21|20|19|18|17|
----------------
```

This way each plot gets a numeric id, which are sorted in "rings", starting with 0. I found that I can calculate:

The number of plots in each ring:

- $count(0) = 1$
- $ count(n) = 8n $  for (n > 0),
- = 1, 8, 16, ...

The index of the first plot in each ring n:

- $firstplot(n) = 1 + 4n(n-1)$  with $firstplot(0) = 0$
- = 0, 1, 9, 25, 49

I am trying to to find the "ring" $n$ of a plot index $x$, which yields the above inequation.

The index of the last plot in each ring $n$:

- $last plot(n) = 4n(n+1)$
- = 0, 8, 24, 48, ...

To find the "ring" $n$ for a given plot $x$ I formulated the above inequality which says, that x has to be inbetween the interval [firstplot(n), lastplot(n)].

Comment: You can use either $n=\left\lceil\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}2\right\rceil$ (from $x\leq 4n(n+1)=(2n+1)^2-1$) or $n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+1}2\right\rfloor$ (from $(2n-1)^2=1+4n(n-1)\leq x$).

Comment: uff ... I know it was easy, but not seeing the square extension is a little embarassing ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in the comment of user10354138 (thanks!) the solution can be calculated using square extension of the inequality. I answer my own question to document my understanding process.

$1+4n(n−1)≤x≤4n(n+1)$

can be transformed to

$ (2n - 1)² <= x <=  (2n + 1)² - 1 $

From the first inequality one can resolve:

$ n <= \frac{\sqrt{x} + 1}{2}$

From the second inequality one gets:

$ \frac{\sqrt{x+1} -1}{2} <= n $

which transforms the inequality to:

$\frac{\sqrt{x+1} -1}{2} <= n <= \frac{\sqrt{x} + 1}{2} $

And since $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ we narrow the interval by calculating the ceil and floor on the left and right side.

$\left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{x+1} -1}{2} \right\rceil = n = \left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{x} + 1}{2} \right\rfloor $